# Make device SD Card windows bootable by an android app

Tags: android

It may seem strange, but I wonder is an android app able to make the SD Card inside the device windows bootable? I thought of making the SD bootable and write ultimatebootcd to it. I did it through windows, but it would be so great if android can do it!

Comment: No reason for this to be closed, it's a perfectly appropriate question - it is not asking for an app recommendation, it is asking if it is possible for an app to do this.  What possibilities are and are not open to applications on a platform is very much a development question.  Incidentally, the answer is most likely no, except on a "rooted" device.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks Chris, I don't know much about the file system in android, i know this much an app can access the SD so I guessed there must be a way to modify it somehow to be bootable!

Comment: If the card is already bootable, you could probably modify what it boots to a degree on an older android device, but on the most recent devices my impression is that you can no longer access the sdcard root folder but only a user-specific folder within it.  However I have not looked into this in detail.  If you already have a custom executable on the card capable of searching the rest of it, you could definitely leave new data or extensions for it to work with.

Comment: Migrating this here was completely inappropriate.  The question concerns technical possibilities of Android as a development platform, specifically what its security model does and does not permit third party application developers to do.  It is NOT an administration, configuration, or usage question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the SD card bootable, you have to modify the boot sector of the card. This can not be done from a standard Android application. If the Android device is rooted, it can almost certainly be done from a native Linux program, or an NDK program.

If the device is not rooted, you can probably not do what you want. As [Chris Stratton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/429063/chris-stratton) commented, if the card is already made bootable, you could probably then change for instance what OS is booted up and how.

Say, there is startup code which loads and boots an OS, then you can change the configuration file for the bootloader. A starter: http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/Boot_an_Iso_image

Comment: if the sd is already bootable any version of android can change the os?

Answer (score 0):

I used Rufus and installed a syslynux on the SdCard from a PC running window 10.then I put the card back into the Moto phone. It's receiving files that I have moved from the internal storage to the card how ever I have not a chance to find out whether they Will open up In the PC or not.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).